# Replace only whole words in MySQL

Tags: mysql

First question here. I'm trying to search and replace in MySQL to replace whole words only. Here's an example section of a string in the database:

> ...has a "front end" (not ending) that you are looking at now...

I want to be able to replace the word *end* while leaving the word *ending* alone.

This is my query so far, but it's not working. It's replacing both instances of *end*.

```
UPDATE mfvjy_content
SET introtext = REPLACE(introtext, 'end', 'endR')
WHERE introtext REGEXP '[[:<:]]end[[:>:]]' AND id = 2
```

Anyone got any ideas on why the word boundaries aren't working? Thanks!

Comment: the word boundaries are filtering the rows of your query (if there is end, it may be also ending). REPLACE replaces all substrings in those rows. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: Ah that makes sense, no wonder it didn't work. I did the word replacement in PHP using preg_replace instead and just inserted the whole string back into the database.